# Configurar Web.Config para IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net

tengo una aplicación ASP.NET, que para poder depurarla tengo que tener configurado el IIS, lo he hecho y me funciona perfectamente, pero hay alguna forma de no tener que usar IIS?

En las propiedades de mi web tengo puesto lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el ISS lo tengo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay alguna forma de poder configurar el web.config, para no tener que crear la aplicación en el IIS??

Quiero poder pasar la aplicación sin tener que hacer que nadie tenga que configurar el IIS y no sé como hacerlo.

saludos!

Comment: No te entiendo. Tienes una aplicación configurada con el IIS, que no es necesario desde Visual Studio, en la configuración del mismo (imagen que muestras) puedes poner "Use default Web Server". Pero ¿que significa "sin tener que hacer que nadie tenga que configurar el IIS"?

Comment: Son cosas diferentes, el IIS es quien levanta tu web, e interpreta que tiene que hacer tu sitio, en tu web config  son configuraciones de como debe funcionar tu sitio. Seria como querer hacer una app sin usar Android o iOS

Comment: Es que voy algo perdida con el tema, si yo le doy a depurar, la aplicación se me abre y me da un error, me dice que configure el ISS etc.. lo configuro y entonces me funciona, pero hay forma de no tener que usar ISS?

Comment: @RogerTorné si le pongo que use default web server me da un error, y dice que configure el ISS...

Comment: hay que ver el error. Siempre necesitas el IIS, puede ser express o no. En tu caso, de esa forma vas publicando o compilando y la web levanta sin depurar.

Comment: Quizas usando el default pero cambiandole el puerto te funcione bien. Normalmente pasa eso

Comment: Es posible usar Apache para su sitio, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247383/how-to-run-asp-net-4-0-website-on-apache-server (en inglés)

Comment: Hola @RamiroBarone si cambio el puerto me sale el mismo error. Voy a mirar lo de Apache, yo lo que quiero es que al abrir la aplicación no tenga que antes configurar nada en el IIS, simplemente abrirla como cualquer otra.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando IIS Express no necesitas configurar nada en la versión normal, solo se ejecuta cuando le das a F5 o Ctrl + F5[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como entras en esta ventana? A mi no me salen estas opciones.. uso Visual Studio 2017..

Comment: click derecho sobre tu proyecto en el explorador de proyectos, propiedades, web.

Comment: no me sale igual...

Comment: Tal vez cuando instalaste tu VS2017 no marcaste la opción para que también se instale IIS Express, podes volver a reinstalar VS o instalarlo manualmente. El instalador aquí: https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=48264

Comment: ademas podes subir una captura de lo que te muestra en la propiedad Web?

Comment: he actualizado el IIS y me dice que tengo la versión más actualizada. Así que no es eso el erro, luego sobre la propiedad web es que directamente no la tengo...